# Conditionally add reference inside loop

Tags: reactjs

I am conditionally assigning difference references (ref=) to elements inside a loop depending on index. I know the below is wrong (although works), how should I refactor?

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ value, index }) => (
  <div className="grid-item">
    {index == 0 && (
      <img className="image-item" src={value.imgUrl} ref={this.bigImage} />
    )}

    {index == 1 && (
      <img className="image-item" src={value.imgUrl} ref={this.secondImage} />
    )}

    {index > 1 && <img className="image-item" src={value.imgUrl} />}
  </div>
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to assign a value based on index. Also make sure to use `===` when comparing values:

```
const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ value, index }) => {
  const ref = index === 0 ? this.bigImage : index === 1 ? this.secondImage : null;
  return (
    <div className="grid-item">
      <img className="image-item" src={value.imgUrl} ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
});
```